# Continuation, callcc method is not defined

Tags: ruby, continuations

I wanted to learn something about Continuation, type several examples from some articles with **callcc** method and I've got the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `callcc' for main:Object
from (pry):2:in `<main>'
```

None of articles have mentioned to include continuation library. So how to fix this problem? Thanks

EDIT: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Continuation.html):

> Continuation objects are generated by Kernel#callcc, after having required continuation.

Comment: The link is for ruby 1.9.2, but your quote from 1.9.3 http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Continuation.html. Maybe here's some inaccuracy but it works for ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste confusion. I meant to post the 1.9.3 docs, as there's really no reason not to upgrade from 1.9.2.

Comment: Right (+1). Then it is a documentation bug in 1.9.2 (and probably 1.9.1). That statement was added in 1.9.3's doc but the behavior is already that way in 1.9.2.

Answer (score 5):

You need to require 'continuation'.

```
require 'continuation'
```